# How can I extract the preceding audio (from microphone) as a buffer when silence is detected (JS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-audio-api, google-cloud-speech, audiocontext

I'm using the Google Cloud API for Speech-to-text, with a NodeJS back-end.
The app needs to be able to listen for voice commands, and transmit them to the back-end as a buffer. For this, I need to send the buffer of the preceding audio when silence is detected.

Any help would be appreciated. Including the js code below

```
 if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, success, function (e) {
        alert('Error capturing audio.');
    });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');

var recording = false;

window.startRecording = function () {
    recording = true;
};

window.stopRecording = function () {
    recording = false;
    // window.Stream.end();
};

function success(e) {
    audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new audioContext();

    // the sample rate is in context.sampleRate
    audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);

    var bufferSize = 4096;
    recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);

    recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        if (!recording) return;
        console.log('recording');
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        console.log(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));
       };

    audioInput.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you need help on: Sending the data to this API? Detect silence? Split your recorded data?

Comment: Sending the data to this API and get output in real time.

Comment: @azhar Does the API support real-time communication?

Comment: Ah so the *silence* part is actually not part of this question... The docs doesn't seem to talk about direct API calls from js, and this may not be a good idea anyway since you'd need your tokens to be visible. **Oh but you mean from node.js???** Then just follow [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs), why are you using this front-end code?

Comment: @Kaiido Actually i want to detect speech from browser mic so i have to send buffer from front end.

Answer (score 30):

I'm not too sure as to what exactly is being asked in the question, so this answer is only intended to give a way to detect silences in an AudioStream.

---

To detect silence in an AudioStream, you can use an [AudioAnalyser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) node, on which you will call the `getByteFrequencyData` method at regular intervals, and check whether there were sounds higher than than your expected level for a given time.

You can set the threshold level directly with the `minDecibels` property of the AnalyserNode.

```js
function detectSilence(
  stream,
  onSoundEnd = _=>{},
  onSoundStart = _=>{},
  silence_delay = 500,
  min_decibels = -80
  ) {
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
  const streamNode = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  streamNode.connect(analyser);
  analyser.minDecibels = min_decibels;

  const data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount); // will hold our data
  let silence_start = performance.now();
  let triggered = false; // trigger only once per silence event

  function loop(time) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop); // we'll loop every 60th of a second to check
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data); // get current data
    if (data.some(v => v)) { // if there is data above the given db limit
      if(triggered){
        triggered = false;
        onSoundStart();
        }
      silence_start = time; // set it to now
    }
    if (!triggered && time - silence_start > silence_delay) {
      onSoundEnd();
      triggered = true;
    }
  }
  loop();
}

function onSilence() {
  console.log('silence');
}
function onSpeak() {
  console.log('speaking');
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
  .then(stream => {
    detectSilence(stream, onSilence, onSpeak);
    // do something else with the stream
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

And [as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53watgqu/) since stackSnippets may block gUM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SpeechRecognition` [`result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/result) event to determine when a word or phrase has been recognized, for example, `ls`, `cd`, `pwd` or other commands, pass the `.transcript` of `SpeechRecognitionAlternative` to `speechSynthesis.speak()` where at attached `start` and `end` event of `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` call `.start()` or `.resume()` on `MediaRecorder` object where `MediaStream` is passed; convert the `Blob` at `dataavailable` event to an `ArrayBuffer` using `FileReader` or `Response.arrayBuffer()`.

We could alternatively use `audiostart` or `soundstart` with `audioend` or `soundend` events of `SpeechRecognition` to record the users' actual voice, though the ends may not be fired consistently in relation to the actual start and end of audio captured by only a standard system microphone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Speech Recognition Recording</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Stop speech command recognition" id="stop">
  <script>
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
      })
      .then(stream => {
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        const synthesis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        const handleResult = e => {
          recognition.onresult = null;
          console.log(e.results);
          const result = e.results[e.results.length - 1];

          if (result.isFinal) {
            const [{transcript}] = result;
            console.log(transcript);
            synthesis.text = transcript;
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(synthesis);
          }
        }
        synthesis.onstart = () => {
          if (recorder.state === "inactive") {
            recorder.start()
          } else {
            if (recorder.state === "paused") {
              recorder.resume();
            }
          }
        }
        synthesis.onend = () => {
          recorder.pause();
          recorder.requestData();
        }
        recorder.ondataavailable = async(e) => {
          if (stream.active) {
            try {
              const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
              const request = await fetch(blobURL);
              const ab = await request.arrayBuffer();
              console.log(blobURL, ab);
              recognition.onresult = handleResult;
              // URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
            } catch (err) {
              throw err
            }
          }
        }
        recorder.onpause = e => {
          console.log("recorder " + recorder.state);
        }
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults = false;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onend = e => {
          console.log("recognition ended, stream.active", stream.active);

          if (stream.active) {
            console.log(e);
            // the service disconnects after a period of time
            recognition.start();
          }
        }
        recognition.onresult = handleResult;

        stream.oninactive = () => {
          console.log("stream ended");
        }

        document.getElementById("stop")
          .onclick = () => {
            console.log("stream.active:", stream.active);
            if (stream && stream.active && recognition) {
              recognition.abort();
              recorder.stop();
              for (let track of stream.getTracks()) {
                track.stop();
              }
              console.log("stream.active:", stream.active);
            }
          }

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/4DVEg6mhFRR94M5gdaIp?p=preview

Comment: `webkitSpeechRecognition` this should be only work in chrome. I want to this in non chrome browsers also.

Comment: So i am trying to using google cloud api in back end and parse speech to text. But how to stream the voice from front end to back end live is my prob.

Comment: @azhar _"I want to this in non chrome browsers also"_ One approach would be to use two `<button>` elements to start or stop recording the `MediaStream`. _"But how to stream the voice from front end to back end live"_ Have you tried using `WebRTC`? The requirement described at OP is _"transmit them to the back-end as a buffer"_, not live streaming a `MediaStream`.

Comment: What data type is the service expecting to be `POST`ed?

Comment: Is any possibility with `socket.io`?

Comment: How is `socket.io` related to requirement? The simplest solution would be to use buttons for user to click when audio should be recorded and paused, then `POST` the recorded audio to server. Does *oogle cloud api speech to text expect an `ArrayBuffer` as input data?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to use `.pause()` and `.resume()`, `.stop()` methods of `MediaRecorder()` to allow user to start, pause, and stop recording audio captured utilizing `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` and convert the resulting `Blob` to an `ArrayBuffer`, if that is what the api is expecting to be `POST`ed to server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>User Media Recording</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Start/resume recording audio" id="start">
  <input type="button" value="Pause recording audio" id="pause">
  <input type="button" value="Stop recording audio" id="stop">
  <script>
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
      })
      .then(stream => {
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        recorder.ondataavailable = async(e) => {
          if (stream.active) {
            try {
              const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
              const request = await fetch(blobURL);
              const ab = await request.arrayBuffer();
              // do stuff with `ArrayBuffer` of recorded audio
              console.log(blobURL, ab);
              // we do not need the `Blob URL`, we can revoke the object
              // URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
            } catch (err) {
              throw err
            }
          }
        }
        recorder.onpause = e => {
          console.log("recorder " + recorder.state);
          recorder.requestData();
        }

        stream.oninactive = () => {
          console.log("stream ended");
        }

        document.getElementById("start")
          .onclick = () => {

            if (recorder.state === "inactive") {
              recorder.start();
            } else {
              recorder.resume();
            }
            console.log("recorder.state:", recorder.state);
          }

        document.getElementById("pause")
          .onclick = () => {

            if (recorder.state === "recording") {
              recorder.pause();
            }
            console.log("recorder.state:", recorder.state);
          }

        document.getElementById("stop")
          .onclick = () => {

            if (recorder.state === "recording" || recorder.state === "paused") {
              recorder.stop();
            }

            for (let track of stream.getTracks()) {
              track.stop();
            }

            document.getElementById("start").onclick = null;
            document.getElementById("pause").onclick = null;
            console.log("recorder.state:", recorder.state
            , "stream.active", stream.active);
          }

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/7caWYMsvub90G6pwDdQp?p=preview