# Issue To Modify Web Speech API?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api, articulate-storyline

Thanks to Matthew Terentjev's great job [Here](https://elearningdifferently.com/speech-recognition-and-storyline) we can do Speech Recognition Online using javascript in Articulate Storyline. The code below is triggered via a button. it is simple and clean and that's what confuses me more, I tried to do some modifications and two of them make me feel like I'm a big failure in life :(

1) First one is even if you add this code :

> recognition.continuous = true;

...Recognition does not continue when the user pauses while speaking. even when I change this part to :

```
recognition.onspeechend = function() {
recognition.start(); // I changed this line from recognition.stop(); 
console.log('Speech ended!');
}
```

2) Next thing I tried unsuccessfully was this: each time user clicks to start a new recognition, the last recognized text should disappear, (Not when the user starts speaking but when he/she clicks the button). in last 24 hours, I was trying to find a solution for this with no success.

There is a button in Storyline project that triggers the code. and a variable that is attached to a text box that is responsible to show the result for user named SpeechReceived.

Here is the code :

```
  var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;
  var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;

  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
  recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
  recognition.lang = 'en-GB';
  recognition.interimResults = false;
  recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

  recognition.start();

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {

    var speechResult = event.results[0][0].transcript;
 //return speech and change storyline variable with a result
    var player = GetPlayer();
    player.SetVar("SpeechReceived",speechResult);  
    console.log('Confidence: ' + event.results[0][0].confidence);
  }

  recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    recognition.stop();
    console.log('Speech ended!');
  }

  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
 console.log('Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error);
  }

  recognition.onaudiostart = function(event) {
      //Fired when the user agent has started to capture audio.
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onaudiostart');
  }

  recognition.onaudioend = function(event) {
      //Fired when the user agent has finished capturing audio.
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onaudioend');
  }

  recognition.onend = function(event) {
      //Fired when the speech recognition service has disconnected.
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onend');
  }

  recognition.onnomatch = function(event) {
      //Fired when the speech recognition can't recognise speech
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onnomatch');
  }

  recognition.onsoundstart = function(event) {
      //Fired when any sound — recognisable speech or not — has been detected.
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onsoundstart');
  }

  recognition.onsoundend = function(event) {
      //Fired when no sound present
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onsoundend');
  }

  recognition.onspeechstart = function (event) {
      //Fired when speech starts
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onspeechstart');
  }
  recognition.onstart = function(event) {
      //Fired when the speech recognition service has begun listening
      console.log('SpeechRecognition.onstart');
  }
```

Comment: Please do not post multiple questions per posts. It makes things impossible to answer and harder for future readers to find. Your first part looks like a duplicate of [Continuous Speech Recognition on browser like “ok google” or “hey siri”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47277211/3702797). For the second part, I'm not sure how text is set in this code and I don't want to go to an off-site resource (*everything needed should be part of the question itself*)

Answer (score 0):

In the first code sample, you might want to not use `recognition.stop()`. And listen for `result` instead of `speechend`. You can stitch together the results to get the entire thing.

Comment: try to create a new instance of SpeechRecognition() on `result` and `start` on the new instance again. Recursive functions all the way.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, instead of using onspeechend use onend to continue listening

```
recognition.onend = function(event) {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('SpeechRecognition.onend');
}
```

This will make the microphone continuously listen.

As for the second question, I don't know. Hope this helps with the first issue at least!